# Pandas cumsum with growth rate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I want to calculate the cumsum but also add a growth rate to each sum.

Growth rate = 0.1

Each row for the [Cumsum with Growth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iBdS.png) column will add a growth component from the previous rows cumsum:
`Row 2 = (1+2) + (1*0.1)`
`Row 3 = (3.1 + 1) + (3.1 * 0.1)`
`Row 4 = (4.41 + 5) + (4.41* 0.1)`

How can I accomplish this without iterating each row in Pandas?

Comment: you might accept and upvote if the answer fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this :

```
col = [df.val.values[0]]
for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    col.append(col[i-1]+df.val.values[i]+col[i-1]*0.1)
df['cumsumwithgrowth'] = col
```

df

```
   val  cumsumwithgrowth
0    1             1.000
1    2             3.100
2    1             4.410
3    5             9.851
```

Answer (score -1):

I would create another column named, CumSumwithGrowth

```
df['cum_sum'] = df.val1.cumsum()
df['CumSumWithGrowth'] = .10*df[‘cum_sum’] + df[‘cum_sum’]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer however this solution will not take into the compounding effect of the growth rate. The cumsum() needs to add the growth effect over each iterations.